# Adobe AIR File or directory access denied on iOS 8

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe, ios8

I've a big trouble with an AIR application that I've developed. It works correctly on iOS 7 and on the previous versions, but there are some problems running on iOS 8.

More specifically, it seems to have problem on the `createDirectory()` method of a File object: when this code instruction has to be executed, the following runtime error is dispatched:

> Error: Error #3001: File or directory access denied.

As I've already written, on iOS 7 all works fine.
Does anybody have this kind of issue? Do you know if this problem belongs to the Adobe AIR side or the new iOS side?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know how AIR handle the filesystem, but I think your problem is caused by this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html

Comment: This is an issue with AIR, which Adobe is tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.applicationStorageDirectory still seems to function with iOS8.

```
_file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("NewDirectory");

if (!_file.exists) {
_file.createDirectory();
}
```